Should I remove the listener from UnityEvent similar to normal C# events?
Do I have to always remove UnityEvent listeners in OnDisable(), when I add them in OnEnable() just like I have always did with normal C# events? Does it affect the performance?

You may be interested in Is it necessary to unsubscribe from C# events when the event owner has already been destroyed?, which also discusses UnityEvents.

You might have side effects when you do not remove the listener. Since you didn't link any code, are you making sure that you are not already added the listener on your next enable? The linked question gives you insights but the main focus of that on is about destroyed GO and not simple toggling them on and off

If you don't invoke the event while the listener is disabled, there will be no performance impact.
If you do invoke the event while the listener is disabled, the listener will still get called, so that has a performance impact, and can potentially lead to incorrect behaviour, if you were expecting the listener to remain completely inert while disabled.
Setting a GameObject to inactive or a script to disabled only prevents the calling of Unity message functions like Update() - it won't prevent C# events, UnityEvents, or direct method calls from running code on the disabled object. This sometimes catches new Unity users by surprise, leading to code changing their game state in ways they thought should be impossible - so watch out for it as a potential source of bugs, especially if you have junior developers on your team.
You'll definitely want to remove the listener before the object is destroyed, unless you know for sure that the publisher of the event will be destroyed first/at the same time.
As Zibelas says, you should also make sure you don't inadvertently double-add the listener without removing it in between, leading to the same function getting invoked multiple times for each firing of the event. Removing it in OnDisable if you add it in OnEnable is a good way to guarantee this, though not the only way.

It's worth noting that any time you call AddListener(), RemoveListener() or RemoveAllListeners(), Unity internally allocates a new list for the listeners (the old list will be garbage collected). This could have a negative performance impact (memory churn leading to extra garbage collection) if many listeners are constantly added and removed. See the source code.

That appears to be true of the removals (horrifyingly — I can't fathom why they would choose to implement it that way), but the AddListener in the code you linked just adds to the existing list. That could lead to allocation if the total number of listeners exceeds the list's current capacity. I wonder if the Unity team would consider getting rid of the excess allocations on removal... They might be doing it in case you're removing a listener from inside the method being invoked? But there are other ways to avoid an error in that case, and addition is not thread-safe anyway, so...

I thought I remembered that AddListener() led to the list being recreated, but analyzing the code again: AddListener() ends up leading to InvokableCallList.m_NeedsUpdate getting set to true, which in PrepareInvoke() causes m_executingCalls to be cleared and repopulated, but not recreated.
